# How do I create this problem as a recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

> T(n) is the running time of an algorithm of input size n. The
>   algorithm solves the problem by breaing it up into 4 problems of the
>   same kind (I take "same kind" to mean we're going to use function T)
>   each of size n/4 . The solution to the original problem is obtained by
>   combining the 4 sub problems in time n (What does this mean in the
>   context of the recurrnce relation ?). Express T(n) as a recurrence
>   relation and derive an expression for T(n) in terms of n , Assume T(1)
>   = 2 .

What i have done

> I came up with T(n) = 4T(n/4)

but I'm really unsure as to what to do next. I would appreciate any guidance, thank you.

Comment: If someone could guide me to a good resource where-in i could learn this topic in depth , i would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: I think the relation is $T(n) = 4T(n/4)+n$, where the $+n$ is the cost of combining the output of the four subproblems.

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but T(n) = 4T(n/4) + c , for some constant c . I don't think it'll be n. If im not mistaken .

Comment: That is how I was interpreting the "combining ... in time $n$" part of the problem statement.